# accessing ELF in memory (Unix/Linux)

Tags: linux, memory, c, process

On Linux (and maybe UNIX), you can access and even modify process's stack with things like `ptrace`, `process_vm_ready`, etc., but is there a way to access the copy of the binary that's being executed that is paged to memory? Not the executable itself, but the copy of it that is moved to memory for execution, never mind the intent behind doing so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the copy of the ELF (`PT_LOAD`) segments loaded in memory through `process_vm_ready()` and such. You can patch the read-only ELF segments using `ptrace` `PTRACE_POKETEXT`. This is used to insert breakpoints in the application code.

See for example [Implementing breakpoints on x86 Linux](http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.com/2011/01/implementing-breakpoints-on-x86-linux.html).

This patches a private copy of the segment memory. This does not patch the original executable file.